# Unable to send parameters to function Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have just started to learn nodejs. I have come across this problem please can anyone show me how to fix this?? I'm unable to send the parameter to the function. I just comes empty.

```html
var getLocation = function(link, callback) {
  console.log(link); //it comes empty | no value 

  if (cond.) {
    console.log("stuff");
  } else {
    var location = value;
    callback(location);
  }
}


getTable(link) {
  var session = obj.createSession();
  session.table(id, 20, function(err, table) { //this block does some stuff work.
    responseCb(link.id, link.jx, err, table);
    console.log("extracted.");
  });

  getLocation(function(link, callback) { //this block sends links as parameter
    console.log(callback);
  });
}

function main() {
  idList = [{
    id: "",
    jx: ""
  }]; //contain data in the array.

  for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
    getTable(idList[i]);
  }
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getLocation` function accepts two parameters: `link` and `callback`. When you call it however you only pass in a single argument:

```
getLocation(function(link, callback) { //this block sends links as parameter
  console.log(callback);
});
```

You pass in a function that has the same parameters as the function that you are calling (`getLocation`). This doesn't make any sence. I assume that what you actually wanted to do was the following:

```
getLocation(link, function() {
  console.log(location);
});
```

- Pass the `link` to the function.
- Pass a callback to the function.
- In the callback, do something with the `location`.